# Setting variables from the response in IntelliJ IDEA's HTTP request generator

Tags: intellij-idea

I am enjoying IntelliJ IDEA's HTTP request generator as an alternative to Postman etc.

Currently, my application uses an ephemeral key for JWTs. You know what kind of pain it is... Every time you restart the application you **MUST** authenticate again, even if the old token is still (temporally) *valid*.

Currently I have to run my OAuth authentication request with my credentials, copy-and-paste the JWT from the output JSON, and then paste in into next request's `Authorization` header

GET http://localhost:8080/api/auth/v1/token
Authorization: CCB [... static token...]

```
{
  "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9....", <== copy that!
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9....",
  "expires_in": 1634292409144,
  "user_details": {
```

And

PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/v1/example/runImportJob
Authorization: Bearer <== paste!

### Question

I know that IntelliJ IDEA supports `{{variables}}`. I'd like to ask if it is possible to set the output of the token invocation into a variable which I'll then reference in the Authorization header

Desiderata

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/v1/example/runImportJob
Authorization: Authorization {{jwt}}
```

And to run the authentication request (`GET .../token`) which ultimately sets the jwt variable, after *jsonpath-ing* the response of corse

Answer (score 3):

You can try using **client.global.set** and **client.global.get** to save/load variables. See the example at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-response-handling-examples.html#script-var-example .